# I'm getting React-Native Component Exception Error

Tags: javascript, mobile, react-native, react-native-ios

Friends, I'm getting this kind of error. When I go through the code, there is no problem. As far as I understand there is a problem with the router-flux component but I do not fully understand the cause of the problem, I updated the packages, deleted everything, installed it again, but no result. I would appreciate it if you could help, friends, thank you in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JwcK.png)

Comment: can you show us the routes definition code?

Comment: The codes I use on router components in this section: https://imguploads.net/image/yAddP                                                                                                               , This section is where the router-flux error is displayed : https://imguploads.net/image/yAASF

Comment: replace the second Stack with Scene component

Comment: sorry mate but it didn't work :(

Comment: Oh,  actually the error is self-explaining and I didn't notice that your code does not have a root scene.

put the form scene inside the root stack
<Stack key="root"><Scene key="Form" ...otherProps /></Stack>

Comment: Should I put this in the root.js directory?